# Firefox flexbox image width

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I'm having some trouble getting my image to take up no more than 100% of the available width of the parent container. I'm only noticing the issue in Firefox 36 (not IE or Chrome). So is it a firefox bug or am I missing something here?

Note: The image should never be larger than it's original size.

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
.container {
  width:300px;
}
.flexbox {
  display:flex;
}

.flexbox .column {
  flex:1;
  background-color: red;
}

.flexbox .middleColumn {
  flex:3;
}

.flexbox .middleColumn img {
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  align-self: center;
  display: block;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="flexbox">
        <div class="column">This is the left column!</div>
        <div class="middleColumn">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400/333333">
        </div>
        <div class="column">This is the right column!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to add `min-width:0` on .middleColumn, if you want to allow it to shrink below its min-content width (the intrinsic width of its `<img>`-child).

Otherwise, it gets the new default [`min-width:auto`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto), which on a flex item will basically make it refuse to shrink below its shrinkwrapped size.

(Chrome [hasn't implemented](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=426898) `min-width:auto` yet. I'm told IE has, in their next-gen rendering engine, so I'd expect that version should behave like Firefox here -- as will Chrome, once they implement this feature.)

Snippet with that fixed:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
.container {
  width:300px;
}
.flexbox {
  display:flex;
}

.flexbox .column {
  flex:1;
  background-color: red;
}

.flexbox .middleColumn {
  flex:3;
  min-width:0;
}

.flexbox .middleColumn img {
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  align-self: center;
  display: block;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="flexbox">
        <div class="column">This is the left column!</div>
        <div class="middleColumn">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400/333333">
        </div>
        <div class="column">This is the right column!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! `min-width: 0;` solved my problem. Firefox applied `min-width: -moz-min-content` and Chrome applied `min-width: auto`.

Answer (score 3):

I have to admit that I'm not sure *why*, but for some reason in Firefox it looks like you have to give the image a width/height (i.e. something other than "auto"). Our old friend `100%` seems to do the trick:

```
.flexbox .middleColumn img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle showing the working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/6qm9xcns/1/). Note that I changed the side columns to `flex:2` to make the result a bit more apparent.

Comment: Thanks but I already knew this, I'll update the question to be more specific that if the image should never be bigger than it's original dimensions.

Comment: My issue isn't exactly the same, but this prompted me to try `width` on the image instead of `min-width`, which fixed my problem.

Comment: This won't work when an image is not as wide as its container, when that container is a flex item. The image will stretch to the full width of the container.

Comment: This also fixed my issue, but as mentioned by @DawnPaladin it was an issue with `max-width: 100%` which wasn't applying correctly. `width: 100%` was the fix. The `height` and `display` in the answer were unnecessary, fixing the classic vertical space on images generally remedied with `vertical-align: middle`.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to get this working with the following:

```
.flexbox {
  display:flex;
}
.flexbox .column {
  flex:1 1 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: red;
}

.flexbox .middleColumn {
  flex-grow:3;
  flex-shrink:3;
}

.flexbox .middleColumn img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

setting `flex:1 1 0;` on all columns sets them to equally grow and do so from the even and miniscule basis of 0px.

You then overide the grow and shrink on `.middleColumn`

`max-width:100%;` is needed as per usual

the magic seems to be `overflow:hidden;` on the item getting flexed.

the other stuff on the image is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the approach is slightly different, maybe strange, but it works. Basically, I fix the max width to the real image width, so it won't pixelate, and use percentage width instead of max-width. If you have, say an `<ul>` (flex) container, the cells will be:

```
li{
   flex-grow: 0;
   flex-shrink: 1;
   flex-basis: auto;
   width: 50%; // for example..

   img{
     display: block;
     max-width: [your real img width in px] // instead of 100%;
     width:100%; // instead of max-width
   }
}
```