# CSS Flexbox app layout issues

Tags: css, flexbox

I have two separate codepens I have been working with, one with the main layout of the site, which works fine, and second is a component that I would like to add inside the left sidebar of the main layout.

The component works perfectly when inside of a container with a set height, it will shrink and stretch just the way I want if inside this type of parent div.

When I add the component into the main layout however it expands the left sidebar, breaking the perfect layout, I want the main layout to be the size of the current browser window, and the page to never scroll. is there a way to tell these sidebars "`.layout-left`" "`.layout-stage`" and "`.layout-right`" to not expand?

**here are the codepens I was talking about:**

Main Layout working: http://codepen.io/AlexBezuska/pen/KwOagy

Working sidebar: http://codepen.io/AlexBezuska/pen/ZYgWYp

Combined (not working): http://codepen.io/AlexBezuska/pen/LEwGJj

Layout CSS I am using:

```
body  {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.layout-middle{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.layout-stage{
  flex: 1 0 320px;
  background: #ffc94e;
}

.layout-left, .layout-right{
  flex: 0 0 320px;
  background: #c9ea5d;
}

.layout-left{
  background: #85d6e4;
}

.layout-header{
  height: 100px;
  background: #92e4c9;
}

.layout-footer{
  height: 150px;
  background: #f7846a;
}
```

Comment: Is either http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qddEoz or http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gppPrp what you are after?

Comment: try to remove (max-height: 100vh) from .layout-middle

Comment: OP, you've set a bounty, why don't you look at answers (and maybe comment if there's still a problem) ?

Answer (score 1):

You currently  have `.layout-header`, `.layout-middle` and `.layout-footer` set to fill the available vertical space, the issue is the length of content within `.layout-left`. There are a couple of ways you can stop the content of `.layout-left` spilling out of the container.

**Overflow method**

By adding `.overflow-y: auto;` to `.layout-left` you can ensure that a scrollbar is shown if its content is longer than its height, stopping the content from spilling out.

```css
.panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  /*padding: 1em;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 1;/*Add this*/
}
header {
  min-height: 32px;/*Add this*/
  height: 32px; /*must be 32px*/
  background: #c0c0c0;
}
footer {
  background: #cfcfcf;
  height: 32px;/*must be 32px*/
}
.select-list {
  /*flex: 1;*/
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /*max-height:16vh; Remove this*/
}
.select-list-item {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 32px;/*must be 32px*/
}

/*===============================================*/
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.layout-middle {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.layout-stage {
  flex: 1 0 320px;
  background: #ffc94e;
}
.layout-left,
.layout-right {
  flex: 0 0 320px;
  background: #c9ea5d;
}
.layout-left {
  background: #85d6e4;
  overflow-y: auto;/*Add this*/
}
.layout-header {
  height: 100px;/*must be 100px*/
  background: #92e4c9;
}
.layout-footer {
  height: 150px;/*must be 150px*/
  background: #f7846a;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout-header">
  <h1></h1>
</div>
<div class="layout-middle">
  <div class="layout-left">
    <!-- start content -->
    <div class="panel">
      <header>panel header</header>
      <div class="select-list" id="select-list">
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
      </div>
      <footer></footer>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <header>Entities</header>
      <div class="select-list" id="select-list">
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
      </div>
      <footer></footer>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <header>Entities</header>
      <div class="select-list" id="select-list">
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
      </div>
      <footer></footer>
    </div>
    <!-- end content -->
  </div>
  <main class="layout-stage">
    <h2>stage</h2>
  </main>
  <aside class="layout-right">
    <h2>right</h2>

  </aside>
</div>
<div class="layout-footer">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gppPrp

**Flex method**

By adding `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column;` to `.layout-left` you can get its contents to fit the available space.

```css
.panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  /*padding: 1em;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 1;/*Add this*/
}
header {
  min-height: 32px;/*Add this*/
  height: 32px;/*must be 32px*/
  background: #c0c0c0;
}
footer {
  background: #cfcfcf;
  height: 32px;/*must be 32px*/
}
.select-list {
  /*flex: 1;*/
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /*max-height:16vh; Remove this*/
}
.select-list-item {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 32px;/*must be 32px*/
}

/*===============================================*/

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.layout-middle {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.layout-stage {
  flex: 1 0 320px;
  background: #ffc94e;
}
.layout-left,
.layout-right {
  flex: 0 0 320px;
  background: #c9ea5d;
}
.layout-left {
  background: #85d6e4;
  display: flex;/*Add this*/
  flex-direction: column;/*Add this*/
}
.layout-header {
  height: 100px;/*must be 100px*/
  background: #92e4c9;
}
.layout-footer {
  height: 150px;/*must be 150px*/
  background: #f7846a;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout-header">
  <h1></h1>
</div>
<div class="layout-middle">
  <div class="layout-left">
    <!-- start content -->
    <div class="panel">
      <header>panel header</header>
      <div class="select-list" id="select-list">
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
      </div>
      <footer></footer>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <header>Entities</header>
      <div class="select-list" id="select-list">
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
      </div>
      <footer></footer>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <header>Entities</header>
      <div class="select-list" id="select-list">
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
        <div class="select-list-item selected">0: bg</div>
      </div>
      <footer></footer>
    </div>
    <!-- end content -->
  </div>
  <main class="layout-stage">
    <h2>stage</h2>
  </main>
  <aside class="layout-right">
    <h2>right</h2>

  </aside>
</div>
<div class="layout-footer">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qddEoz

Answer (score 1):

**[Fixed CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVyVeE)** (also works on Firefox)

I made 3 changes :

**1)** I've set the height of the body to the desired one :

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

**2)** I've given to the left container the right boxing model :

```
.layout-left, .layout-right{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

**3)** In order for the panels to not overflow on Firefox, I've added this :

```
div {
  min-height: 0;
}
```

This last setting is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896807/pre-code-element-with-horizontal-scrollbar-breaks-the-flex-layout-on-firefox) by a developer who works on the flex model at Mozilla. Of course you'd better set it only on the relevant parent divs but this was simpler.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the main layout to be the size of the current browser window, and the page to never scroll.

In this case you need to set a `max-height` for the elements, too, at least for `layout-middle`.

Comment: but setting a max-height means I have to assume the users screen size, I want it to be dynamic. I need layout middle to always be:

. layout-middle height = browser window's height - (header height + footer height)

Comment: If the max-height is expressed in vh and not in px it always use the same percent of the browser window, making the layout dynamic enough but keeping the same proportions between the elements.

Comment: Can you show me an example using the codepen?http://codepen.io/AlexBezuska/pen/LEwGJj  I am not able to get it working...

Comment: Let me sign up, I never used it.

Comment: @glasses : done. Everything except borders now is expressed in vh, and it seems to work, within the limits of the codepen small pane: http://codepen.io/Marco_Bernardini/pen/ogKBQj

Comment: Not exactly what I am trying to do, I want the panels to expand to fill the left column, the header and footer, and select-list-item need to be 32px http://codepen.io/AlexBezuska/pen/emqgwo

Answer (score 0):

.layout-left needs `display: flex;` and `flex-flow: column;` I also added a .container wrapper with `display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100vh;` and removed most properties from body. forked pen: http://codepen.io/oosby/pen/GJJqvP